# SuiteScript 2.0 file.load method does not accept relative path of a .xml file

Tags: javascript, netsuite, relative-path, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have developed a Suitlet script that, in particular, loads an .xml file for further processing using the `file.load` method with an absolute path. I want to use a relative path, but when I do so, it won't work.

Basically, I'm providing the `file.load` method with the absolute path of an .xml file.

I expect the same behavior with a relative path provided instead, but it throws an error.

Both my Suitlet and .xml are in the same folder next to each other.

Forks fine:

```
var xmlTemplateFile = file.load({ id: 'SuiteScripts/printXml/template.xml' });
```

Doesn't work:

```
var xmlTemplateFile = file.load({ id: 'template.xml' });
```

Error message:

> {"type":"error.SuiteScriptError","name":"RCRD_DSNT_EXIST","message":"That
>   record does not exist. path: template.xml

I expect `file.load`, provided with a relative path, to load my .xml file seamlessly.

Comment: Try using this `./template.xml`

Comment: Thanks for quick answer! I have tried all variations ./template.xml, /template.xml, but it didn't work

Comment: Are you sure that your code is inside `SuiteScript/printXml/`? I mean both xml and your code file are inside `SuiteScript/printXml/`?

Comment: Yes, both files are in     SuiteScripts/printXml/

Comment: Could you give a short explanation of why you need a relative path so we could possibly find another solution?

Comment: @Adam, Thanks for your reply! I was totaly fine with absolute path before I realized that my working directory is put inside SuiteBundles/Bundle ${unique_#} directory after deployment into production. Since that, the absolute path does not lead to my .xml file which makes the whole Suitlet useless.

Comment: @ShepshukVlad see [here](https://github.com/michoelchaikin/netsuite-mapreduce-util/blob/master/SDF/FileCabinet/SuiteScripts/MOS%20Map%20Reduce%20Utility/mos_mapReduceUtil.ts#L78) for a workaround

Comment: @michoel, nice workaround! Actually I have done similar thing about path being built as SuiteBundles/Bundle #, where bundle # is taken via runtime module. This works for any files inside a Bundle # directory though, while your solution provides more flexible way of handling the files. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`file.load()` does not accept paths relative to the current file. Not much you can do about it other than submit a feature request to NetSuite.

Comment: It's worth noting here that the Help Center documentation is very poor in a lot of areas -- this being one of them. The parameter is described as being a relative path though it's actually an absolute path.

Answer (score 0):

This should work with ./template.xml. e.g.
var xmlTemplateFile = file.load({ id: './template.xml' });